# How to customize LongListSelector or ListBox Design in WP8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

i like to customize my LongListSelector or ListBox in my own way so can any one help me to design it..
 **MY Code..**

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="345" Margin="10,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413">
                <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="list_organization" Height="340" Margin="10,0"/>

</StackPanel>
```

This is my code to bind the long list..

```
org = await client.searchOrganization(txtQuery.Text);
            if (org != null)
            {
                var query = from c in org
                            select new { c.name,c.id,c.time,.. };
                list_organization.ItemsSource = query.ToList();//bind the query to longlist
            }
```

i want like this design page..

[image]

how to do it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove explicit widths and heights. And if you only have a single `LongListSelector` inside the `StackPanel`, you can remove the `StackPanel`.

Individual items for the listbox-like containers is done by using the `DataTemplate` to replace `ItemTemplate`. Check the following MSDN link for more information: [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Basically, here is how you do it:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="list_organization" Height="340" Margin="10,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- your XAML for individual item goes here -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: thanx it works.... but im getting my data displayed in horizontal way.. half of the data gets hide.. even if i changed to vertical i cant see my complete data..

Comment: without adding the orientation for stack it works goog.. is it ok..?

Comment: I cannot answer your questions because I don't know what you want nor how you are doing it.